# android relativelayout, a mess

Tags: java, android

In the editor, the buttons are lined up like how it should be, but when in the actual device the buttons are messed up. Why is this so?

[image]

[image]

[image]
Here is the fxml file for the navbar, it uses a Relative layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/navbar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/homeBtn"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/home_icon" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/optionsBtn"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/options_icon" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/micBtn"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/homeBtn"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/mic_icon" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/connectionBtn"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="240dp"
        android:background="@drawable/con_icon" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/aboutBtn"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="310dp"
        android:background="@drawable/about_icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Kindly please help me, I am new to android and I am still experimenting. No matter how much I change the x positions of the buttons it won't stay in their place when it is already compiled and run on the android, but when on the editor it looks fine.

Comment: I suggest you to clarify your question before a storm of downvotes hits you. We can't understand what you are asking for

Comment: Do you really need a `RelativeLayout` for a navigation bar that just has a single row containing buttons? Why don't you just use a `LinearLayout` or maybe a `TableLayout`?

Comment: No, I don't. I'd like to get an explanation tho as to why this happens.

Comment: Why not use LinearLayout with horizontal orientation and equal weights to all the buttons?

Comment: I'm new to android, I do not know those things

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are applying different margins to the buttons. That's why not all of them have the same visual distance to their neighbours (`marginStart`).

You would have a lot less trouble aligning buttons in a row using a `LinearLayout` and weight the `Button`'s width, like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/homeBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/home_icon" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/optionsBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/options_icon" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/micBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/mic_icon" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/connectionBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1""
        android:background="@drawable/con_icon" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/aboutBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/about_icon" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Please note the width of every `Button` set to `0dp` and the additional weight set to `1`, which causes every `Button` to have the same witdh. Apply additional margins as desired...